# How can I upload picture from android app to server?

Tags: android, file-upload, android-camera, image-uploading, retrofit2

I have developed a little part. It can take the picture only not storing now.I want to upload picture (using camera) from android app to server. I have used retrofit library, web service(asp.net). How can I do that?

MANIFEST:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

CODE:

```
public class UploadPhotoActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    static final int REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE = 1;

    ImageView imageView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_upload_photo);

        imageView=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);

    }


    public void SelectPhotoMethod(View view){

        Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
            startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        }

    }
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
            Bitmap imageBitmap = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
            imageView.setImageBitmap(imageBitmap);
        }
    }

}
```

[image]

Comment: `I want to upload picture (using camera) from android app to server`. Impossible. You cannot use the camara gor upload.

Answer (score 3):

1. You can use `MultipartEntity` to upload `MultiPart` image to server or
2. You can also use well known `Volley` or `Retrofit` library to upload image to server with minimal codes.

**MultiPart**

[Uploading Camera Image, Video to Server with Progress Bar](http://www.androidhive.info/2014/12/android-uploading-camera-image-video-to-server-with-progress-bar/)

**Volley or Retrofit**

1. [Android Volley Tutorial to Upload Image to Server](https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/android-volley-tutorial-to-upload-image-to-server/)
2. [Upload Image From Android App Using Retrofit 2](https://medium.com/@adinugroho/upload-image-from-android-app-using-retrofit-2-ae6f922b184c)

**More Tutorials:**

1. [Upload File To Server](http://androidexample.com/Upload_File_To_Server_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=83)
2. [Android Upload Image using Android Upload Service](https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/android-upload-image-to-server/)

Hope this will help~